# Почему создание экземпляра RecyclerView излишне?

Tags: java, android, ооп, recyclerview, объекты

Изучаю в Android RecyclerView, при ,казалось бы ,логическом

```
RecyclerView myRecycler = new RecyclerView(this);
        myRecycler = findViewById(R.id.myrec);
```

Появляется предуприжденее

> Variable 'myRecycler' initializer 'new RecyclerView(this)' is
>   redundant

На работоспособность не влияет,но хотелось бы понять почему так.

Comment: Вы либо программно создаете рециклер (первый случай), либо инициализируете уже существующий (случай два)

Comment: Потому и не влияет на работоспособность, что обьект созданный  в первой строке не используется в дальнейшем. Соответсвенно и создание его излишне.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ранее вы создали для своей активити (фрагмента) xml-разметку, где указано, какие виджеты (классы `View` и его наследники, как `RecyclerView`, `TextView` и тп.) будут использоваться на экране, а так же их свойства (размер, цвет и тп.).

Метод `setContentView()` активити (или `inflate()` фрагмента) парсит (инфлейтит) xml-разметку и преобразует декларативный xml-язык разметки в дерево полноценных java-объектов виджетов с указанными свойствами.

метод `findViewById()` возвращает эти, уже созданные по описнию в разметке, java-объекты по идентификатору, назначеному в той же разметке, поэтому програмное создание этого объекта и не требуется, он уже создан ранее.

Это, естественно, относится ко всем виджетам, объявленым в разметке, а не только к `RecyclerView`